# Elasticsearch. Kibana creates big log files. How to turn off?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch for storing goods in online store.
In /var/log/elasticsearch kibana regulalry creates log files. Big log files. So that, It doesn't leave me a free space. As I have only 15Gb SSD on my VPS this becomes a huge problem. And each time logs are being created by Kibana they becomes bigger.
What should I do? Why do I need those log files? The only decision I see is to turn off logs. **How can I do this?**
What is the best practice for this case? If I do not delete it, then I, sooner or later, will run out of free space, even if I would have 100Gb of free space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their website you have to change your configuration to suppress all the logging.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.5/kibana-server-properties.html

logging-silent:true will disable all the logging.
However I recommend logging-quiet:true. Otherwise you won't see the error logs.